# open vswitch and open virtual network in openstack

Tags: openstack, openvswitch, openstack-neutron

I have a local lab which does not have a physical switch and consists of 3 servers which are connected to each other Nics.

Now I want to implement vlans, want to know is it possible to setup vlans only with OVS and without any physical switches?

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to implement VLANs"? OVS can generate VLAN tags, and even normal Linux VLAN interfaces can. How are the nodes connected - does each node have two connections? If so, I don't think it will work, since you need a single interface for tenant traffic as far as I know.

Comment: I meant there are two type of external network in openstacl , flat and vlan.
I know about flat network all nodes are reside in one subnet for example 10.10.10.0/24

but I have two there nodes that are resided out of 10.10.10.0/24 thus I have to implement vlans as oppose to flat .

Unfortunately I don't have a physical switch to understand vlan tagging and transfer the packet/frame to proper destination. 

So now I want to know that if the OVN or OVS can do something to prevent me buying a physical switch in my topology?

Comment: How are the nodes connected - does each node have two connections?

Comment: nodes are connected to each others through their Ethernets with cat 5 cables, no switch just connect directly to each other.
yes each nodes has at leas two nics, one for vm management and the other for internet.

Comment: But how are the nodes connected to each other? If you have three nodes A, B and C, is A connected to B, then B to C? In this case I wonder how A communicates with C. Or are there two connection from each node to the other nodes? In this case, I don't think your setup works, since you need a single interface for tenant traffic if I am not wrong.

Comment: server A has 4 ports , my PC is connected to port 1 (10.10.10.11/0) and my laptop to port 2 (10.10.10.0/24) and server B to port 3 (10.10.13.0/24) and server C to port 4 (10.10.12.0/24), I have set up bridge network for each port then I created and connected some VMs on each node ( PC,Laptop,servers) and assign them a static IP from their range. 

Server A has 3 KVMs/Qemu vms  which I have installed Openstack and first compute node on them. 
Server  B and C act as compute node for the Oponstack, my PC and Laptop aren't part of Openstack. Laptop is the gateway for internet connected to wifi